# how to write and read .xlsb file in C# without using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, xlsb

I have multiple .xlsb templates that have 5-6 sheets in them.
First, 2-3 sheets are where I need to add data dynamically so that the 4th and 5th sheets can generate data based on the macro/formulas written in them.
Can you guys help me out with what can be used for this?

What I have already tried?

- ExcelDataReader - But it did not work for xlsb consistently
- LinqToExcel - I could read the data from the custom templates by creating the models and fetch the related data through Linq

I am not finding anything that I use to write/export data to xlsb to specific sheets
Can anyone help me out here as I cannot convert the template to another format, it has to be xlsb.